# PHP/Mysqli caching mysql host? Not respecting low TTL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, rds, amazon-aurora

We're using PHP on AWS, with RDS/Aurora.

This works by exposing an endpoint for the cluster, which was CNAME records to the currently active mysql nodes.

As we add/remove reader nodes, in the case of a failover, this endpoint is updated automatically, with a 5 second TTL.

As such, our app should see and respond to the new nodes very quickly.

We're noticing after a failover, we get 'Mysql has gone away' for much longer than the 5 second period. We've had instances of this being 30 minutes, at which point we restarted Apache and it resolved the issue.

It seems as though somewhere in the application, the database is not querying the endpoint DNS and resolving the new endpoints, therefore still pointing at a node which is no longer there.

We do use Persistent connections (for performance), which was the obvious culprit, however we've then tested with these turned off, and same behaviour exists.

We're using PHP 7.1, with Mysqli. We have a singleton class around the mysqli connection, but even if this kept the same connection open it would only last the time a single script executed, which is typically a few milliseconds.

Any guidance as to where the caching may be occurring?

Comment: Is this a DNS TTL?  (I have had poor luck with such.)

Comment: So, every time a MySQL node fails, you update the DNS record with the new node URL? What if you have more than one running nodes, to which node does the DNS point?

Comment: @HoomanBahreini This is all automated by AWS, it's part of their hosted database solution

Comment: Do you have anything like Dnsmasq installed on your server? This would explain the caching your experiencing. Fun fact... AWS recommends using something like Dnsmasq to speed up connection times even though it can lead to the exact problem you've got here, so it's very possible you could be.

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear if your issue is DNS related on the remote services or caching on your own (AWS) local network/services. This is the first thing to look into.

To my knowledge Linux does not cache DNS lookups and nor does Apache/PHP (unless you're using mod_proxy, in which case look into `disablereuse Off` setting). With this in mind I expect that your Apache service restart causing it start working was likely a coincidence.

My first suggestion would be to force a fail-over and then immediately check with the name servers from several different geographical locations **and using a terminal from your AWS server** to see how long it takes the same servers to report updated results. The chances are name servers are simply ignoring your TTL, or perhaps just '*treating it as a suggestion*'.

The long and the short of it is that ***DNS TTL is just a suggestion*** to resolving name servers as to how long to cache. There is nothing to enforce name servers to actually abide by what you set. And the reality of it is, **many name services don't follow your setting exactly or even at all**.

If the name-servers **are** updating as quickly as expected elsewhere, *but not on your AWS server* and mysql still can't connect; this suggests *caching somewhere on your server* or more likely within the AWS network. Unless the caching is directly on your server, which as discussed above I believe is unlikely, I doubt there is much you can do about this.

Ultimately updating a DNS record and using a low TTL as a fail-over solution is likely never going to achieve consistent <1 min fail-over speeds.

You may want to look into alternative methods such as [ClusterControl](https://severalnines.com/product/clustercontrol/mysql-replication-database-management-system) or a proxy method such as [ProxySQL](https://www.proxysql.com/).

Comment: The records on the nameserver are updating very quickly. So I'm back to finding where the caching is. Apache restart always works

Comment: Have you checked the disablereuse setting?